# Why I cannot give height to 100% when postion fixed is not written?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I made a sidebar with bootstrap classes and when i need to expand the height of sidebar full the height of screen it doesn't work with height:"100%" css property but when i added one more property position:"fixed" and it started working and my sidebar take full height now. What is the relation between position and height?
Code:

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
   
        
export default function Bar() {


return (
  <>
    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0" style={{width: "4.5rem",backgroundColor:"#cee8ff",height:"100%",position: "fixed"}}>
      <a href="" className="d-block p-3 link-dark text-decoration-none">AMS</a>
      <ul className='nav nav-pills nav-flush flex-column mb-auto text-center'>
        <li className="nv-item my-2">
          <a href="" className="nav-link active py-3 border-bottom" aria-current="page"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li className='my-2'>
          <a href="" className="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li className='my-2'>
          <a href="" className="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bolt"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li className='my-2'>
          <a href="" className="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li className='my-2'>
          <a href="" className="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li className='my-2'>
          <a href="" className="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Height 100% doesn't mean "100% of the height of the screen" (that would be 100vh by the way) it means "100% of the height of the element's parent." By setting the position to fixed, you're essentially making the element's parent the viewport, which is why 100% and the height of the screen become the same thing.

Comment: Height 100% means full height of its parent container. So if  you want to take full height of screen,  you should use 100vh. or you can use js for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to everyone else's comments, set the `body { height: 100vh; }` so that the div height, at 100% matches the parent's height (i.e. the body). Code below to show you the effect:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; /*added this */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0" style='width: 4.5rem; 
            background-color:#cee8ff; 
            height:100%;'><!-- removed the position fixed from the style attribute -->
  <a href="" class="d-block p-3 link-dark text-decoration-none">AMS</a>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-flush flex-column mb-auto text-center'>
    <li class="nv-item my-2">
      <a href="" class="nav-link active py-3 border-bottom" aria-current="page"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class='my-2'>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class='my-2'>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bolt"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class='my-2'>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class='my-2'>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class='my-2'>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-3 border-bottom"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation but what you did here i did replicated to my react app where in index.css file i have added height: 100vh in the body and also removed position from the main file still it doest get full size why?

Comment: Have a look at the [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) and see what's going on.

Comment: But when i give 100vh to the div root in react app it shows perfectly fine whereas in body it doen't work the flow is this sidebar div is a child of root(div) and root(div) is a child of body

Comment: The root div will also have to be set to the height of the body too for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `height: 100%`, you don't set it to 100% of the page, you set it to 100% of its' parent. When you set `position: fixed`, the parent position and sizes are ignored, and thus it fills the whole page height.